# Opencv-Python cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS error

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using opencv 3.2.0 and python 3.5.2 currently. When executing following code:

```
videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
fps = videoCapture.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
size = (int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
```

I encountered following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videoEditor.py", line 29, in <module>
    fps = videoCapture.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_FPS'
```

Could anyone tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In OpenCV 3.2, drop the `CV` in front of the flag.
This should work just fine

```
videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
fps = videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
size = (int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Eshirima answer solved the problem.
But just for reference i want to show you one more way of performing these operations as mentioned in docs: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

```
videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
width  = int(videoCapture.get(3))
height = int(videoCapture.get(4))
fps = int(videoCapture.get(5))
```